# Azure App Gateway v1 - URL redirection to same domain with different URL?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Is the following URL rewrite supported in Azure App Gateway v1?

https://app.demo.com/myWeb/ redirects https://app.demo.com/my/

If so, how do I implement the same?

**Update:**
we are using app gateway v1 and from what I've read, it's not supported there. but URL rewrite is supported in v2

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct URL rewrite feature is only available on Application Gateway v2 SKU. You can follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#rewrite-configuration) to implement rewrite URL path.